# Craft Commerce: Adding Number fields to product and cart pages

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm adding the following to my `_product.html` template to try and add a number to a line item in the same way that notes are added. I'm using the following input:

```
<input type="number" name="numberDistance" step="any" placeholder="Add your minimum distance in mm..." id="distanceNum">
```

I then add the following to my cart template to output the field:

```
Min distance: {{ item.numberDistance }}
```

When I add an item to my cart I get the following error:

**Craft\Commerce_LineItemModel and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "numberDistance".**

What is going wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make use of lineitem "options" param. You can attach as many options as you like using something like:

```
<input type="number" name="options[numberDistance]" step="any" placeholder="Add your minimum distance in mm..." id="distanceNum">
```

And then these will be avaliable on the lineItem once saved using

`{{ item.options['numberDistance'] }}`

More info can be found on the [Craft Commerce docs](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/add-to-cart#line-item-options-and-notes)